# PHP Function and SQL Failing

Tags: php, mysql, function, null

I recently converted a code block into a function so I can call it easily more than just once. My problem is that as soon as I related the block to a function it fails the SQL query every time. Here's my code block:

```
    function checkEvent()
{
if(!empty($_GET['e']))
    {
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE EventID = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['e']) . "'");

        if($sql && mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)
            {
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql))
                    {
                        $eventid = $row[0];
                        $eventname = $row[1];
                        $desc = $row[2];
                        $time = $row[3];
                        echo $_GET['e'];
                    }
            }               
        else
            {
                echo $sql;
                $failure = "Num Rows Error encountered: " . mysqli_error($link) . " / Num Rows: " . mysqli_num_rows($sqlE);
            }
    }
}
```

Now, I've added `echo`s in the relevant places to check and where it currently says `echo $sql;` if I change that to `echo "Fail.";` then it will indeed do that. I have tried to get the result as a number of rows and that comes back blank. I don't understand this as my `EventID` is an `AUTO INCREMENT` and as such HAD to start at 1. I've triple checked the first entry is 1 as well.

I'm probably not seeing something really obvious, I just can't understand why this code block stopped working the instant I placed a function block around it.

Comment: Where do you declare "$link"? I would suspect that's the culprit.

Comment: [**variable scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue? where is your connection `$link` defined? try adding it as a function parameter `function checkEvent($link)` or as `global $link` inside the function or if in a class `$this-link`.

Comment: $link is declared inside my base.php which contains all my db connection details. It is included at the top of the document that this function is within. As I said it worked perfectly before-hand so surely the $link variable is passed still? It's been declared in the base.php which is the very first thing in this file to be called.

Comment: Answered my own stupid damn question. Thanks guys, really appreciate this and learned something I won't soon forget! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$link` doesn't exist inside your function. You either need to pass that as a parameter to the function or skip it entirely and use the "current" DB connection.

"current" in quotes because while it should work just fine while you're utilising a single database connection for the entire process, as soon as you'd start using multiple connections (to connect to multiple databases,) this approach would fail terribly.